# c# WinForm Marquee Progress Bar does not scroll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

Background:

I have a VB6 application that currently does some processing in a database and then calls a COM exposed c# class. The c# class then does some other long processing on a background worker. During that time, I have a status window pop up that has a status label as well as a progress bar. I want the progress bar to show with the marquee style but it does not animate. It is visible and functions properly but only as the Block style. I can set the value and it will display the Block style but when I set the style to marquee, it just does not do anything. Is it the VB6 application that's killing it? How do I get the animation to display properly?

What I have done:

- I have made sure to set Application.EnableVisualStyles(); (I tried
  setting it in different places!)
- I have programmatically set the marque style and even verified the
  style is set while debugging.
- I have tried calling ProgressBar.Show(); even though its already
  visible on the form.
- I have tried using both a static and non-static (displayed below) helper class.

Here is the small helper class I created that I use.

```
internal class EStatusHelper
{
    private EStatus status = null;

    public void ShowStatusForm<T>(Action<T> process, T arguments)
    {
        var bg = new BackgroundWorker();

        bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        using (status = new EStatus(bg.RunWorkerAsync))
        {
            bg.DoWork += (o, args) =>
            {
                process(arguments);
            };

            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
            {
                status.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            };

            status.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateStatusMessage(
        string message)
    {
        if (status != null)
        {
            if (status.StatusMessage.InvokeRequired)
            {
                try
                {
                    status.StatusMessage.Invoke(
                        new Action<string>(UpdateStatusMessage),
                        message);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            else
            {
                status.StatusMessage.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Form EStatus just to show how the BackgroundWorker gets started.

```
public partial class EStatus : Form
{
    public Action ShowAction = null;

    public EStatus()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public EStatus(Action a) : this()
    {
        ShowAction = a;
    }

    private void EStatus_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShowAction != null)
            this.BeginInvoke(ShowAction);
    }
}
```

And here is the basic call to use the helper function.

```
// helper variable that can be passed around.
// Also tried Static methods instead of passing around a local variable.
var helper = new EStatusHelper();
helper.ShowStatusForm(MethodToInvoke, paramsToPass);
```

Thank you!

Comment: The important code is missing.  No point in having a "status" form that doesn't show status.  Doing that far too often causes the UI thread to go catatonic and stops moving the marquee.  Calling Application.EnableVisualStyles() like that is pretty fatal.

Comment: @HansPassant The UI does not freeze. The form is shown modal just fine and the progress dialog can be updated just fine using the same technique as in the UpdateStatusMessage() method. It can only be updated as a "block" style progress bar though. It will not display as a marquee style. Please see updated code.

Comment: As per the windows documentation: The Marquee style is supported only on these platforms: Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003. Are you running your app on any of those?

Comment: @alstonp I am running my application on both Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows XP Pro x64 machines with the same results. FYI. Make a simple Windows Forms Application and add just a progress bar with the style set to Marquee in Windows 7 or 8 and hit Run. It will scroll all day.

Comment: @HansPassant "Application.EnableVisualStyles() like that is pretty fatal" - I have tried this in many different places including the recommended location -> constructor of my COM exposed class that starts the entire process. It has not had any ill effects or good effects for that matter anywhere. I have read the MSDN regarding this saying it should be called before any controls are created. The example above is just 1 of many and just happened to be its location at the time of posting. Anything else pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.